# Using CONCATENATE to populate a sum formula in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that has numbers for a particular year and then subtotals for that year.

[image: screenshot of example]

The number of instances in a year can vary and there may be a year that doesn't exist i.e., 2018 might be skipped.  The title of the totals row is always "FYXX Totals."  I have a for loop that goes through the entire column and looks for "FY" Then if it falls within one of three categories (FY1-FY2, FY3-FY7, FY3-FY9; these being variables that represent a year).  What I need is for the loop to sum the number in column D, E, F...when "FY" is found.  I think using CONCATENATE might be the way to go but I am not sure a) exactly how to do that or b) if that is even the best way to go about it.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim SumRow As Integer

Set rng = Range("C4:C" & NextRow)

For Each cell In rng
If Left(cell.Value, 2) = "FY" Then
    If 2000 + Int(Mid(cell.Value, 3, 2)) <= FY2 Then 'This is the if statement for the fisrt category
        'Here would be the sum function when the if statement is triggered
    End If

    End If
Next cell
```

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: When you say *sum the number in column D, E, F…*, is it always the same set of columns you need to sum? In that case either get the `Value` of each cell and add those numbers into a VBA variable, or alternatively use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(myrange)`? Is it more complicated than that in some way that you haven't explained?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the question.  I will try and explain the data sheet a little better:  What I have are rows of data that are applicable to a particular year.  Underneath all the data for that year is a row that totals the data.  I could sometimes be 2 rows, 5 rows whatever to a year if any.  If there are now rows of data for that year the year is not displayed.  Underneath all the data and totals row I have a master summary table that totals the totals rows in categories based on what years they are.  My code that I have shown is for the first category.

Comment: Please post a picture of the sheet and explain what you want to calculate.

Comment: @nekomatic as was pointed out to me I should have posted "my answer" into my original post as an edit.  But please take a look at my answer that has a picture of a spreadsheet and a little more explanation.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've edited (when my edit is accepted) the picture into the question, but I still don't understand what you need. Is column D the one headed *Non-Nuc BAWP*? If so what's in columns *E, F …* as referred to in the question, and what decides whether you need to include those columns in the sum?

Comment: E, F etc. are just more columns of similar data.  Once I know how to do it for column D I will know how to do it for the rest.  Yes, Column D is the one headed _Non-Noc BAWP_.  So in the case of the code in original question I would need to sum "D5."

Comment: @nekomatic your edit to the original posdt has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadSheet_Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63UIa.png)

The second if loop (right now written for the first category) would need to sum the just the zero that is in column D next to FY17 Total.  Keep in mind that sometimes row for FY18 may exist so this macro would have to be able to grab that as well should it exist.  But in this case what would have to go into cell "D" & NextRow would be =SUM(D5).

Comment: You should edit this into your original post, not as an answer. If it has been a while you might want to notify the other person with a comment (use @username so they get a notification).

Answer (score 0):

My best attempt at understanding what you're after is that you want to place a formula in each cell of column D where the cell in column C contains `FYxx Total`, where `xx` meets certain other criteria. That formula should contain the sum of all the cells in column D for which the cell in the corresponding row of column C contains the same value of `FYxx`.

The easiest way I can think of to achieve this is to use the `SUMIF` function:

[image: sumif example]

The formula `=SUMIF(B$2:B$999,LEFT(C3,4),D$2:D$999)` in cell D3 calculates the sum of all cells in column D where the cell in the corresponding row of column B matches the criterion, i.e. is equal to the first four characters of cell C3.

Unless there are further instances of the same `FYxx` value elsewhere in column B, the ranges in the first and third arguments of the `SUMIF` can cover the whole table, which I've assumed here extends to row 999, so you can keep those the same for each cell you place this formula in. You only need to change the  row for the cell in column C in the second argument.

In fact if you really want, you can place exactly the same formula in each `Total` cell in column D:

```
=SUMIF(B$2:B$999,LEFT(INDEX(C$2:C$999,ROW()-1),4),D$2:D$999)
```

Here the `INDEX` function looks up the appropriate cell in column C based on the row of the cell that the function is placed in.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your need please supply a more detailed example showing the row and column headers and giving the addresses of exactly which cells should be summed!